# Colour of certain objects

Tags: quantum-optics

How do internal structural bandgaps define object colour? For example, if an object is transparent, are the energy bandgaps in the structure too large for even the 400 nanometer photon to be able to make a transition? If an object is black and opaque then the object absorbs all and reflects none of the light incident on it. I'm guessing that the band gaps are too small and even the 700nm red photon has a higher energy, so although it gets absorbed and jumps the atoms to a much higher energy level than that of the next available band state, the return of the atoms to the ground state are in subsequent steps of consequentially smaller jumps, translating through each of the available states. Thus the emitted wavelengths are all infra red or beyond. But what if an object is yellow? How does the band structure work in that case? How does the entire energy incident get remitted in terms of the intermediate yellow wavelength?

Comment: Please don't just demote my question, let me also know why...

Comment: A band gap is a property of insulators and semiconductors in which electrons can be reversibly separated from their atoms or molecules and in which they don't become trapped almost immediately. This isn't universally the case and it is not the universal the mechanism by which solids can obtain a non-trivial absorption spectrum. In the infrared absorption is dominated by molecular rotations and vibrations and in the visible electronic excitations and transfers in a molecule can absorb and emit light without the need for a conduction band.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if an object is transparent, are the energy bandgaps in the structure
> too large for even the 400 nanometer photon to be able to make a
> transition?

I wouldn't use the term "bandgap", but yes.  For example small molecules (like $H_2$, $O_2$, $CO_2$, etc.) have very few allowed energy states at room temperature.  Kinetic and rotational energies can increase the bandwidth a bit, but otherwise these are poor absorbers in the visible light range.

You're correct that black materials absorb much of the light that falls on them and then release it via IR. Colorful materials are rarely due to the energy bands of a single atom.  Instead they tend to be larger molecules that can move charge around.  The molecule can have an excited state that corresponds to the correct energy to be a good absorber in that range.  See for example this article on [Charge-transfer complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-transfer_complex)

> How does the entire energy incident get remitted in terms of the
> intermediate yellow wavelength?

It doesn't.  Most pigments show color not by re-emitting energy as a different color, but instead by partial absorption.  The pigment will only strongly absorb certain wavelengths.  Meanwhile others are not absorbed and are reflected or scattered from the surface.  So the color seen is not the entire incident energy, but just the fraction that is not absorbed.